# How to properly align wordpress search results posts with css?

Tags: css, wordpress

My site has problems because I want to align 3 posts in a row, and would like to adjust properly to the sidebar on the right. Since I use margin-right: 18px; on each block, it cannot be moved to the right corner, just like it is on the main page: virmodrosti.com

here is the problem:
http://www.virmodrosti.com/?s=minerali

compare with the main page and you'll know what I mean.
I also added the picture [wordpress theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWKi7.png)

Currently width of each post block is 260px, if I change it to 264 it jumps into the next row, and only 2 posts are displayed in each row instead of three.

On the picture there are three issues to fix them, but I will be glad to know the solution for the main problem.

Kindly let me know, thank you.

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem. Can you make it more clear?

Comment: I need to make lenght of  each posts displayed wider to properly fit 844px, just like the main page. so if you compare the main url and the one with search results, you will know what I mean. each post has 250 width, but to properly fit it sohuld be probably around 270 but since it has 19px right margin it will fall to the next row below. There is too much space between right sidebar and those 3 posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add css to every 3rd `.post` element to remove the 18px margin like this:

```
#content-a .post:nth-of-type(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

And to calculate width with this margin missing you can add:

```
#content-a .post {
    width: calc(33.33% - 12px);
    /*12px = 18px margin * 2 and divided by the three columns)*/
}
```

Since your page breaks to two columns it would be worth wrapping both code snippets above in a media query e.g.:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px){
    #content-a .post {
        width: calc(33.33% - 12px);
    }
    #content-a .post:nth-of-type(3n) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It worked with this entry #content-a .post:nth-of-type(3n) {
 margin-right: 0px;
} Great! I would like to know if there is anything you can do with p-info to move it to the bottom for all posts and navigation since older and newer entries should be at the bottom left.

Comment: @Techuser you could try absolute positioning p-info and then add a bit of extra padding to the bottom of the .post. Can you make my answer as correct? thanks

Comment: Done. Thank you, it really made my theme beautiful.